# accessing google maps via UIWebView - illegal?

Tags: iphone, maps, forward, geocode

New to iPhone development.  Working on first app.  I'm accessing google maps via UIWebView to forward geocode an address using "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=my address".  It works, although it has this quirk of requiring you to hit "Back" button and then the "Detail" button (provided by the navigation bar) to get back to the screen from whence you started.  If anyone knows why it does this, I'd love to hear.  My real question, however, is this a legal use of google maps?  Since I intend this app for commercial use, am I violating Google's rules + regs?  If it is illegal, what's my alternative?  Thanks.

Comment: I take it you haven't ready any license or agreements that you were expected to agree to?  Check those out.

Comment: Are you talking about Google licenses and agreements?  If so, where would I have encountered them?

Answer (score 2):

Using Google Maps in a `UIWebView` is permitted by Google's Terms of Service.

In iOS 6 Apple switched the maps backend from Google to its own, and even though it is technically possible to use Google's map tiles in `MKMapView`, that is not permitted by Google's ToS.

Here's the clarification directly from [@GoogleMapsAPI](https://twitter.com/GoogleMapsAPI/status/253551273796841472) on Oct 3 '12:

> **Q:** There are some iOS apps using GMaps tiles, so I want to know they are legal or not legal with licence violation.
>
> **A:** Direct tile access is not permitted. Using JavaScript API in a web view is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an iPhone developer and the last thing i know is objective-c, but have you considered using the Google Maps API?

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#mapsformobile
It says

> The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 has been developed to cater to mobile devices, and is suitable for browser applications targetted at both the desktop and devices that include a web browser with a full JavaScript implementation, such as the Apple iPhone.
>
> For browser based applications targetted at devices not suitable for using the JavaScript API, the Static Maps API delivers map images in GIF, JPG, and PNG formats, including markers and polylines. Note that it is not permitted to use the Static Maps API outside of browser based applications.

I'd surely try it, at least the Static Maps API cos it's extremely easy to use, and the overall agreement allows commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using the Bing API, it's designed to be used client and server side. So you should be able to make a web service request without using UIWebView.

Rich

Comment: Would someone mind telling me what is so awful about that suggestion? It's a solid API, we use it in preference to Google Maps.

Comment: answers are suppose to answer the question not offer a suggestion (that's what comments are for)